# Where do I find the unit tests for the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mono

I've heard that Microsoft release the unit tests for the .NET Framework. Is that true?
If so, how do I get them?

I'd like to implement classes similar to ones implemented by .NET and I would like to reuse their unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has not released unit tests for the .NET framework.

What you may have heard is that Microsoft has provided the Mono team with Silverlight unit tests (which include some pieces of the framework) for their implementation of Moonlight.  These tests are not public.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sources for the .NET framework here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.
You also might find this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx) from Scott Guthrie helpful. But I'm not sure if there are unit test included. I only know for sure they are for the [ASP.NET MVC source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com).

Comment: Viewing the .NET source would disqualify Jader Dias from contributing to the Mono project, which I suspect he might be due to the Mono tag.